# RxJS iif with multiple conditions and Angular 9

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am attempting to create a service with Angular that returns a particular data set.

The shape of the object returned from the api is this:

```
{
  status: string,
  totalResults: number,
  results: [array of objects]
}
```

so on my service, I want to return an observable of the array of results when status is "ok" and totalResults > 0 (meaning I don't want to return an empty array).

my service is looking like this but I'm struggling with the syntax of iif and want to combine it with pluck.

```
getData(): Observable<result[]> {
 this.http.get<APIResponseObj>(
            this.url
        ).pipe(
            mergeMap(v =>
                iif(
                    () => v.status && v.totalResults,
                    this.results$(v)
                )
            )
        )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, you could set up your request to use the `map` operator to decide what to return based on your conditions, since `map` will wrap whatever value you return in a new Observable by default (so, no need to use `iif()`):

```js
    getData(): Observable<result[]> {
        return this.http.get<APIResponseObj>(this.url).pipe(
            map((v) => {
                if (v.status && v.totalResults) {
                    return v.results;
                } else {
                    return []; // Although you're stating to not want to return an empty array, in my opinion, an empty array would fit your case, since you're planning to return Observable<result[]>
                }
            })
        );
    }
```

The method above should return the Observable you're hoping to store in `this.results$`

```js
this.results$ = this.getData(); // Returns Observable<result[]>
```

After that, you could, for example, use the `async` pipe on the view to both subscribe and get the values (the `ngFor` loop won't attempt to display anything if the array is empty):

```html
<div *ngFor="let res of (results$ | async)">
  {{res}}
</div>
```

I hope that helps!